# Passing props in map function doesn't work. Passing it as key works

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-map

I'm passing an array as props from the App.js to Component B. The array:

```
myOptions: [
{
    id: 1,
    option: "Option1"
},
{
    id: 2,
    option: "Option2"
},
{
    id: 3,
    option: "Option3"
}
]
```

From the App.js I'm passing it to Component B:

```
<ComponentB 
    options={this.state.myOptions}
/>
```

ComponentB:

```
import React from 'react';

import ComponentC from './ComponentC';


function ComponentB (props) {

  function renderOptions(key) {
    return(
      <ComponentC
        key={key.option}
        optionContent={key.option} //this is my question
        answers={props.option}
      />
    );
}

    return (
        <div>
        <h3> ComponentB </h3>
        {props.options.map(renderOptions)}
      </div>
    );

}

export default ComponentB;
```

The ComponentC only displays the optionContent:

```
import React from 'react';

function ComponentC(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.optionContent}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ComponentC;
```

Although the code works correctly, I'm not sure why in the `renderOptions` function, I need to use `key.option` to pass the `optionContent={key.option}` prop. When I use `props.option`, it doesn't work.

Is it because the `renderOptions` function is nested in the `ComponentB` function?

Comment: Looks like apples and oranges to me. On one hand you're looking at a single element of `props.options` and on the other you're looking at all of `props.options`. What do you mean by "it doesn't work" exactly?

Comment: I think there's some confusion to where the variable in renderOptions is coming from. map is providing the key arg. Also, what is the value of props.option as it looks undefined.

Comment: @ggorlen I don't get any error in the console or on the screen.

Comment: Instead of `key` argument you can use `props` and then use `props.option`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should understand how `map()` works.

In your code,

```
function ComponentB (props) {
  function renderOptions(key) {
    return(
      <ComponentC
        key={key.option}
        optionContent={key.option} //this is my question
        answers={props.option}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
      <div>
      <h3> ComponentB </h3>
      {props.options.map(renderOptions)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You use the `map()` like this `{props.options.map(renderOptions)}` and it looks okay.

But you should know something about `map()`'s arguments.

you can read it

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Normally, `map()` has 3 arguments and be used 2 of them. `currentValue` and `index`.

and, return to your code again.

you passed your function `renderOptions()` itself.

it means `renderOptions()` can get all arguments from `map()`

You can touch `currentValue`, `index` and other things.

But, `renderOptions()` has only one argument `key`.

(If you want to touch all arguments you should write like this `function renderOptions(v, i, arr)` )

So, you can touch only `key` as `currentValue`.

and `currentValue` has each item of Array.

```
{
    id: 1,
    option: "Option1"
}
```

You have to rewrite your code like that.

```
function renderOptions(v,i,arr) {
    return(
      <ComponentC
        key={v.id} // because the key should be unique.
        optionContent={v.option} 
        answers={arr} // Actually, I don't understand this purpose.
      />
    );
}
```